# Module imported in one function NameError in another function called afterward

Tags: python-3.x, function, import, module

I have a Python3 script that installs pip3 and and a digitalocean module for creating droplets.

I have broken up the script into 3 functions, Install(), Run(), and Uninstall. In the Install function I can install pip3 and the digitalocean module.

I have multiple functions that I want to call in the Run() function. 
At the beginning of Run() I import the digitalocean module. When I call another function that uses this module I get "NameError: name 'digitalocean' is not defined".

Everything I have read says that I can import in a function and then use that import in another function. I don't know if Python3 is diffrent? Something I am missing?(has to be)

Here is relevant code that has the bulk pulled out. Let me know if you need more.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import importlib.util
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import sys
import subprocess
import time


accessToken                 = 'ABC'
dropletName                 = 'newDropletAndTag'
tagName                     = dropletName

def Install():
    pass
    #This function installs the package and other things if they are not already present. 


def CreateDroplet():
    newDroplet = digitalocean.Droplet(  token       = accessToken, 
                                        name        = dropletName,
                                        region      = 'NYC1',
                                        image       = 'ubuntu-16-04-x64',
                                        size_slug   = 's-1vcpu-1gb',
                                        ssh_keys    = sshKeysList, 
                                        backups     = False
                                        )    

def Run():
    import digitalocean
    myManager = digitalocean.Manager(token=accessToken)
    myDroplets = myManager.get_all_droplets(tag_name=tagName)

    Install() 
    CreateDroplet()


def Main():
    #START OF SCRIPT
    print('\n\n\n')
    print('---- Start Of Script ----')
    Run()
    print('---- End Of Script ----')
    print('\n\n\n')
    #END OF SCRIPT
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to EXPLICITLY say that the import module will be global.

Change the Run() to :

```
def Run():
    global digitalocean
    import digitalocean
    myManager = digitalocean.Manager(token=accessToken)
    myDroplets = myManager.get_all_droplets(tag_name=tagName)

    Install() 
    CreateDroplet()
```